# Does anyone know how to apply dependencies on cloudflare worker?

Tags: cloudflare, nodemailer, cloudflare-workers

I was trying to create a free service using cloudflare but i need to use googleapis and nodemailer. So I need to add the dependencies.

Comment: https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/wrangler/module-system/

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how to access Google Cloud APIs from under a Cloudfalre Worker script. You would just need to create a Google Cloud [service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts) (IAM) with required permissions and a JSON [private key](https://github.com/kriasoft/cloudflare-starter-kit/blob/863b74df820bc7edbddcd41b9f632fed409a7a49/env/.local.env#L19) for it.

```js
import { getAuthToken } from "web-auth-library/google";

export default {
  fetch(req, env) {
    cosnt accessToken = await getAuthToken({
      credentials: env.GOOGLE_CLOUD_CREDENTIALS,
      // TODO: List the required GCP scopes here
      scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform",
    });

    // Access any of the Google Cloud REST APIs using that token
    const url = `https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects`;
    const headers = new Headers({ authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}` });
    const res = await fetch(url, { headers });
    const data = await res.json();

    // ...
  }
}
```

#### References

- https://github.com/kriasoft/web-auth-library — OAuth 2.0 library for Cloudflare Workers
- https://github.com/kriasoft/cloudflare-starter-kit — Cloudflare Workers Starter Kit